# Multiple arrays after exporting from json?

Tags: php, arrays, json

Here's my JSON file:

```
{"settings":{"name":"pracamojanowa","owner":"kaitek666","id":"AhuJagUjAHu8"}}
```

I wanted to get the `owner` from this array. I have all values exported into an array, but when I try..

```
$data2['settings']['owner'][$_SESSION['user']];
```

I get a `false` return and an error:

**Warning: Illegal string offset 'kaitek666' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\login\home.php on line 84**

That was a bit weird for me, but my `print_r` exported array looks a bit unusual as well:

```
Array ( [settings] => Array ( [name] => pracamojanowa [owner] => kaitek666 [id] => AhuJagUjAHu8 ) )
```

I need to access the `owner` value and the above PHP code to return `true`.

Comment: How are you populating the `data2` array?  `owner` has a string value, and attempting to get the `$_SESSION['user']`th element of that string is tossing your error from the looks of things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$data2['settings']['owner']
```

Contains the value of the owner.

By doing `$data2['settings']['owner'][$_SESSION['user']];` you are attempting to treat the string `"kaitek666"` as an array, hence the error.

If you just want the value of the owner `$data2['settings']['owner']` will contain what you want. if you want to check to see if the owner matches the `user` value in `$_SESSION` then do:

```
if($data2['settings']['owner'] === $_SESSION['user']){
    echo "Owner match!";
}else{
    echo "Owner does not match!";
}
```

Comment: Now I see my mistake. I have no clue what I wanted to achieve. Appreciated a lot!